# Application linked to msvcp140d instead of msvcp140

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

In short, Question is how to link application towards `MSVCP140.dll` instead of `MSVCP140D.dll` ?

Description:

While porting application to Windows XP encountered the following issue:

Application failed to start because `MSVCP140D.dll` was not found.

**Target** is `Windows XP Professional 2002 SP 3` with `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017` installed

**Host** is `Windows 10` with `Visual Studio 2017`

I verified that `MSVCP140D.dll` is missed on target, but `MSVCP140.dll` is present.

I tried both **Release|Debug** Configuration and also **MDd|MD** Runtime Library configurations.

Platform Toolset is set to **v141_xp**

Comment: It is supposed to be straight-forward, you *must* deploy the Release build of your program.  *And* the DLLs that it uses.  The latter clause tend to be the troublemaker.  Just use the debugger, switch to the Release build and press F5.  Look at the Output window, it shows the load notifications of every DLL used by your program.  The one that is loaded just before the MSVCP140D.dll load notification causes the problem.

Comment: Hans Passant, thank you, it was indeed straight-forward. I tried to perform Release build, by changing Configuration->Release in drop-down menu within Project Properties. What I had to do is to set Configuration->Release in Configuration Manager window for my Project.